# Xamarin.forms ScanOverlay how to show last scan item into label or something like in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, overlay

Xamarin ScanOverlay how to show last scan item into label or something like and I want Button for go back for some reason. I have scenario where I have to scan continue that time I have to show last scanned item on same ScanOverlay.
Basically I want to design page in XAML I have tried with

```
xmlns:scandit="clr-namespace:Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified;assembly=Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified"


<ContentPage.Content>

<Grid 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <scandit:BarcodePicker 
        x:Name="thePicker" />

    <Label
        Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Text="{Binding BottonText,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Button
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        Command="{Binding DoneCommand}"
        HeightRequest="50"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        Text="Done"/>
</Grid>
```

Getting error in to

```
<scandit:BarcodePicker x:Name="thePicker" />
```

how to solved this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am not able to get scandit:BarcodePicker from scandit namespace itself even they have mention in UWP Docs but it wouldn't work